# PHP replace text except image alt

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace `"hello"` with `"guys"` except the image src and alt with PHP (case insensitive).

From

```
Hello hello HELLO <img src="hello.jpg" alt="hello" />
```

I want

```
Guys guys GUYS <img src="hello.jpg" alt="hello" />
```

or

```
guys guys guys <img src="hello.jpg" alt="hello" />
```

I tried with `str_replace`, `str_ireplace`, `preg_replace` but no result.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: writing some code would be one way to do it. or printing the text/html onto a piece of paper and then using whiteout to erase the text you don't want. We're not here to do your job for you. **YOU** write the code. if it doesn't work, then you post that code and someone may try to help you.

Comment: are there going to be multiple `<img>` in the string?

Comment: hello, this is the complete code `$words = array();
$links = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `keyword`, `link` FROM `articles` where `link`!='".$act."' ") 
or die(mysql_error());
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{
if (!empty($row['keyword']))
{
$words[$i] = $row['keyword'];
$links[$i] = '<a href="'.$row['link'].'.html" class="ared">'.$row['keyword'].'</a>';
$i++;
}
}
$text = str_ireplace($words, $links, $text);`

Comment: but the problem is that it replaces also the alt tags and src from my text

Comment: the "complete" question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753137/php-replace-words-to-links-except-images

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match both hello following both alt=" and src=" you could use a "negative lookbehind" for both of those. Something like:

```
$string = 'Hello hello HELLO <img src="hello.jpg" alt="hello" />';
preg_replace('/(?<!(src|alt)=")hello/i', 'guys', $string);
```

Comment: almoust perfect...  but my keyword has multiple words, it does not work! Here is the complete "problem" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753137/php-replace-words-to-links-except-images

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a "Negative Lookahead." Here's my proof of concept code.

```
<?php
$string = "Hello, hello, HELLO hello.jpg";
print preg_replace("/hello(?!.jpg)/i", 'Guys', $string);
```

Prints

```
Guys, Guys, Guys hello.jpg
```

Comment: Well that doesn't preserve the case of your results, but the `(?!.jpg)` is the important part. You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: the result is Guys Guys Guys <img src="hello.jpg" alt="Guys" />

Comment: Thank you @jacobwalker0814 but the alt property should not be replaced

Comment: what about `hello.png` or `hello.gif`

Comment: Kellerdavis has a better answer