# PHP replace words to links except images

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

My code is

```
$words = array();
$links = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `keyword`, `link` FROM `articles` where `link`!='".$act."' ") 
or die(mysql_error());
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{
if (!empty($row['keyword']))
{
$words[$i] = '/(?<!(src="|alt="))'.$row['keyword'].'/i';
$links[$i] = '<a href="'.$row['link'].'.html" class="ared">'.$row['keyword'].'</a>';
$i++;
}
}
$text = preg_replace($words, $links, $text);
```

I want to replace Hello with Guys except img src and alt.

From

```
Say Hello my dear <img src="say-hello-my-dear.jpg" alt="say hello my dear" />
```

I want

```
Say Guys my dear <img src="say-hello-my-dear.jpg" alt="say hello my dear" />
```

The current code, replaces only when my keyword has only 1 word.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: the previsouly suggested correction was not relevant.

Still:

- I would suggest you not to use any regex but only str_replace in your case if you have a performance constraint.
- You must change your MySQL functions that are legacy: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: @user2233781: I do not understand what '?' stands for. Personaly, I would have written:

    $words[$i] = '/!(src="|alt="|src=\'|alt=\')'.$row['keyword'].'/i';

Comment: I think I did not understand the problem. As you can see, this simple example is perfectly working: http://ideone.com/MDR5HF

Comment: hello - you can see it here - http://www.tedsdiets.com/beyonce-lemonade-diet.html - it replaces the word "lemonade" but it replaces also the .jpg <img alt="lemonade" src="http://www.tedsdiets.com/images/diets/beyonce-<a href="lemonade-diet.html" class="ared">lemonade</a>-diet.jpg"

Comment: and in your example, the keywords should be hello and goodbye

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I can't believe it took me that long to understand that you're trying to parse big chunks of HTML with regular expressions.
Read the answer to this question:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I want to replace all words not only 1

Comment: What I meant was all words, but just the first time they come up.

Comment: can you give me a solution for my problem?

Comment: I will user count, but what if the Image with that keyword is first? Than it will replace the image tag with a link, and that's not ok...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I updated the code to work better.

I'm unsure exactly what the issue is but looking at your code I wouldn't be surprised that the negative look behind regex isn't matching multiple word strings where the "keyword" is not the first word after the src or alt. It might possible to beef up the regex, but IMHO a complicated regex might be a little too brittle for your html parsing needs. I'd recommend doing some basic html parsing yourself and doing a simple string replace in the right places.

Here's some basic code. There is certainly a much better solution than this, but I'm not going to spend too much time on this. Probably, rather than inserting html in a text node, you should create a new html `a` element with the right attributes. Then you wouldn't have to decode it. But this would be my basic approach.

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum <img src=\"lorem ipsum\" alt=\"dolor sit amet\" /> dolor sit amet";

$result = array(
  array('keyword' => 'lorem', 'link' => 'http://www.google.com'),
  array('keyword' => 'ipsum', 'link' => 'http://www.bing.com'),
  array('keyword' => 'dolor sit', 'link' => 'http://www.yahoo.com'),
);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($text);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($result as $row) {
  if (!empty($row['keyword'])) {
    $search = $row['keyword'];
    $replace = '<a href="'.$row['link'].'.html" class="ared">'.$row['keyword'].'</a>';

    $text_nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//text()');
    foreach($text_nodes as $text_node) {
      $text_node->nodeValue = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $text_node->nodeValue);
    }
  }
}

echo html_entity_decode($doc->saveHTML());
```

The `$result` data structure is meant to be similar to result of your `mysql_fetch_array()`. I'm only getting the children of the root for the created html DOMDocument. If the `$text` is more complicated, it should be pretty easy to traverse more thoroughly through the document. I hope this helps you.

Comment: this is my text ` significant <img src="yes-lemonade-diet.jpg" alt="lemonade" /> amount of weight. Beyonce looks spectacular just because of the diet she consumed. If you want to have a perfect figure like Beyonces then you have got to check out Beyonce lemonade Diet. ` and this is the result `significant  amount of weight. Beyonce looks spectacular just because of the diet she consumed. If you want to have a perfect figure like Beyonces then you have got to check out Beyonce <a href="lemonade-diet.html.html" class="ared">lemonade</a> Diet. ` The image is missing!