# Edit php urls to link function

Tags: php, hyperlink, preg-replace

I have a php function that changes urls to links. But I have problem when I insert for example pictures in format `<img src="http://somelink.com/picture.jpg">` it also changes the inside url to link. How should I prevent this?

```
<?php
$string='http://www.somelink.com';
echo makelink($string);

function makeLink($string){

$string = preg_replace("/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i","$1http:$2",$string);
$string = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</A>",$string);
$string = preg_replace("/([\w-?&;#~=\.\/]+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?))/i","<A HREF=\"mailto:$1\">$1</A>",$string);

return $string;
}

?>
```

So, for exaple when I have input like this:

```
<img src="http://somelink.com/img.jpg"> http://somelink.com
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
<img src="http://somelink.com/img.jpg"> <a href="http://somelink.com" target="_blank">http://somelink.com</a>
```

What my code do now is:

```
<img src="<a href="http://somelink.com/img.jpg" target="_blank">http://somelink.com/img.jpg</a>"> <a href="http://somelink.com" target="_blank">http://somelink.com</a>
```

I hope you see the problem

Comment: Can you give examples of the input, the problematic output, and the output you desire?

Comment: I edited some examples of the problem @MikeBrant

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP replace words to links except images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753137/php-replace-words-to-links-except-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **negative lookbehind** in REGEX to check if something **DOES NOT** precede what you want to match.

Say that you had this expression for matching URLs:

```
((?:http(?:s)?://)(?:www\.)?[-A-Z0-9.]+(?:\.com)[-A-Z0-9_./]?(?:[-A-Z0-9#?/]+)?)
```

This expression would match the following types of URLs:

```
http://www.example.com
http://example.com/
https://www.example.com/seconday/somepage#hashes?parameters
https://www.example.com/seconday/
http://www.example.com/seconday
http://example.com/seconday
http://example.com/seconday/
```

So then you could just add a negative lookbehind to the front of it to check for a quote, tick or equal sign.  If it finds one of those, then it won't make a match.

Here is what the negative lookbehind would look like:

```
(?<!(?:"|'|=))
```

And you can just put that in front of the other REGEX.  Here is what this means:

```
(?<!   (?:   "|'|=   )   )
 1      2      3     4   5
```

1. `(?<!` Negative Lookbehind - This says make sure that whatever is coming up next cannot be present in front of the string.
2. `(?:` Non-Capturing Parenthesis - We are going to be putting a group consisting of a quote `"`, tick `'` or equal sign `=`, but we don't want to capture it.  We just want to check for any one of those.  By default, REGEX remembers anything inside of a parenthesis `(`, so we add the `?:` to tell it not to.
3. `"|'|=` Look for either a quote `"`, a tick `'` or an equal sign `=`.
4. `)` Closing parenthesis for the "or" grouping of `"|'|=`
5. `)` Closing parenthesis for the negative lookbehind.

Okay, putting it all together, the REGEX would look like this:

```
(?<!(?:"|'|=))((?:http(?:s)?://)(?:www\.)?[-A-Z0-9.]+(?:\.com)[-A-Z0-9_./]?(?:[-A-Z0-9#?/]+)?)
```

[Here is a link to a demo of the REGEX](http://regex101.com/r/dL0kJ7)

[Here is a link to a demo of the REGEX in a PHP script](http://ideone.com/qFLedv)

Really, the only thing I had to do to the REGEX to get this to work in PHP was to escape the tick, since I was using ticks to enclose my expression.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I just had to edit the code little, because it worked just for urls with .com ending. so I changed the part with `(?:\.com)` to `(?:\.)` and now it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
<?php
    $html = '<img src="http://somelink.com/img.jpg"> http://somelink.com';
    $link = preg_replace('%<img src="(.*)/(.*?)">\s*(.*?)\s*$%m', '<img src="$1/$2"> <a href="$1" target="_blank">$3</a>', $html );
    echo $link;
`   //<img src="http://somelink.com/img.jpg"> <a href="http://somelink.com" target="_blank">http://somelink.com</a>
?>
```

***DEMO***
https://ideone.com/fgGaYK